# Problemas de compatibilidad del navegador con window.URL.createObjectURL(this.stream)

Tags: javascript, jquery, stream

hola tengo problemas con esto `window.URL.createObjectURL(this.stream)` quiero tomar una foto con mi webcam utilizando un query llamado **say-cheese** pero mi navegador es **firefox version 63.0** y creo que por problemas de compatibilidad no se ve el video que esta capturando la camara. A continuacion pongo todo el script donde esta la siguiente funcion:

```
SayCheese.prototype.getStreamUrl = function getStreamUrl() {
        if (window.URL && window.URL.createObjectURL) {
            return window.URL.createObjectURL(this.stream);
        } else {
            return this.stream;
        }
    };
```

Script:

```
/*
     * Say Cheese!
     * Lee Machin, 2012
     * http://leemach.in, http://new-bamboo.co.uk
     *
     * Minimal javascript library for integrating a webcam and snapshots into your app.
     *
     * Handles starting up the webcam and rendering the element, and also capturing shots
     * in a separate canvas element.
     *
     * Depends on video and canvas, and of course, getUserMedia. It's unlikely to work
     * on anything but the newest browsers.
     */

    var SayCheese = (function() {

        var SayCheese;

        navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
                                  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                                  navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                                  navigator.msGetUserMedia ||
                                  false);

        window.AudioContext = (window.AudioContext ||
                               window.webkitAudioContext);

        window.URL = (window.URL ||
                      window.webkitURL);

        var ERRORS = {
            NOT_SUPPORTED: 'NOT_SUPPORTED',
            AUDIO_NOT_SUPPORTED: 'AUDIO_NOT_SUPPORTED'
        }

        SayCheese = function SayCheese(element, options) {
            this.snapshots = [],
            this.video = null,
            this.events = {},
            this.stream = null,
            this.options = {
                videoSource: null,
                snapshots: true,
                audio: false,
                width: 320
            };

            this.setOptions(options);
            this.element = document.querySelector(element);
            return this;
        };

        SayCheese.prototype.on = function on(evt, handler) {
            if (this.events.hasOwnProperty(evt) === false) {
                this.events[evt] = [];
            }

            this.events[evt].push(handler)
        };

        SayCheese.prototype.off = function off(evt, handler) {
            this.events[evt] = this.events[evt].filter(function(h) {
                return h !== handler;
            });
        };

        SayCheese.prototype.trigger = function trigger(evt, data) {
            if (this.events.hasOwnProperty(evt) === false) {
                return false;
            }

            this.events[evt].forEach(function(handler) {
                handler.call(this, data);
            }.bind(this));
        };

        SayCheese.prototype.setOptions = function setOptions(options) {
            // just use naïve, shallow cloning
            for (var opt in options) {
                this.options[opt] = options[opt];
            }
        }

        SayCheese.prototype.getStreamUrl = function getStreamUrl() {
            if (window.URL && window.URL.createObjectURL) {
                return window.URL.createObjectURL(this.stream);
            } else {
                return this.stream;
            }
        };

        SayCheese.prototype.createVideo = function createVideo() {
            var width     = this.options.width,
                height    = 150,
                streaming = false;

            this.video = document.createElement('video');
            this.video.autoplay=true;

            this.video.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
                if (!streaming) {
                    height = this.video.videoHeight / (this.video.videoWidth / width);
                    this.video.width = width;
                    this.video.height = height;
                    streaming = true;
                    return this.trigger('start');
                }
            }.bind(this), false);
        };

        SayCheese.prototype.linkAudio = function linkAudio() {
            this.audioCtx = new window.AudioContext();
            this.audioStream = this.audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(this.stream);

            var biquadFilter = this.audioCtx.createBiquadFilter();

            this.audioStream.connect(biquadFilter);
            biquadFilter.connect(this.audioCtx.destination);
        };

        SayCheese.prototype.takeSnapshot = function takeSnapshot(width, height) {
            if (this.options.snapshots === false) {
                return false;
            }

            width  = width || this.video.videoWidth;
            height = height || this.video.videoHeight;

            var snapshot = document.createElement('canvas'),
                ctx      = snapshot.getContext('2d');

            snapshot.width  = width;
            snapshot.height = height;

            ctx.drawImage(this.video, 0, 0, width, height);

            this.snapshots.push(snapshot);
            this.trigger('snapshot', snapshot);

            ctx = null;
        };

        /* Start up the stream, if possible */
        SayCheese.prototype.start = function start() {

            // fail fast and softly if browser not supported
            if (navigator.getUserMedia === false) {
                this.trigger('error', ERRORS.NOT_SUPPORTED);
                return false;
            }

            var success = function success(stream) {
                this.stream = stream;
                this.createVideo();

                if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
                    this.video.mozSrcObject = stream;
                } else {
                    this.video.src = this.getStreamUrl();
                }

                if (this.options.audio === true) {
                    try {
                        this.linkAudio();
                    } catch(e) {
                        this.trigger('error', ERRORS.AUDIO_NOT_SUPPORTED);
                    }
                }

                this.element.appendChild(this.video);
                this.video.play();

                this.trigger('success');
            }.bind(this);

            /* error is also called when someone denies access */
            var error = function error(error) {
                this.trigger('error', error);
            }.bind(this);

            return navigator.getUserMedia({ video: {
                optional: [{
                    sourceId: this.options.videoSource
                }]
            }, audio: this.options.audio }, success, error);
        };

        SayCheese.prototype.stop = function stop() {
            this.stream.stop();

            if (window.URL && window.URL.revokeObjectURL) {
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.video.src);
            }

            return this.trigger('stop');
        };

        return SayCheese;

    })();
```

hasta ahora pienso que es por problemas de compatibilidad

Answer (score 1):

estuve revisando el código del `jquery` y resolvi donde estaba el problema de compatibilidad:

Esta es la función anterior:

```
var success = function success(stream) {
                this.stream = stream;
                this.createVideo();

                if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
                    this.video.mozSrcObject = stream;
                } else {
                    this.video.src = this.getStreamUrl();
                }


                this.element.appendChild(this.video);
                this.video.play();

                this.trigger('success');
            }.bind(this);
```

lo que hice fue sustituir

```
if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
                        this.video.mozSrcObject = stream;
                    } else {
                        this.video.src = this.getStreamUrl();
                    }
```

por:

```
try {
                    this.video.srcObject = stream;
                } catch (e) {
                    if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
                        this.video.mozSrcObject = stream;
                    } else {
                        this.video.src = this.getStreamUrl();
                    }
                }
```

Quedando la funcion de esta manera:

```
var success = function success(stream) {
            this.stream = stream;
            this.createVideo();

            /*if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
                this.video.mozSrcObject = stream;
            } else {
                this.video.src = this.getStreamUrl();
            }*/

            try {
                this.video.srcObject = stream;
            } catch (e) {
                if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
                    this.video.mozSrcObject = stream;
                } else {
                    this.video.src = this.getStreamUrl();
                }
            }

            if (this.options.audio === true) {
                try {
                    this.linkAudio();
                } catch(e) {
                    this.trigger('error', ERRORS.AUDIO_NOT_SUPPORTED);
                }
            }

            this.element.appendChild(this.video);
            this.video.play();

            this.trigger('success');
        }.bind(this);
```